# Reorder items on the X axis in ggplot

Tags: r

I have a graph that looks like:

[image: this]

I'm hoping to have the dates go in chronological order, but I really can't figure out how. My code to make the graph is as follows:

```
label1 <- data.frame( x = 1,  y = 4, label = "")
label2 <- data.frame( x = 2, y = -4,  label = "")

ggplot(data = Q10, mapping = aes(y = Rating, x = Week, group= StudentFactor, colour=StudentFactor))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  geom_smooth(method = 'loess',  colour= "black", aes(group=1), se= FALSE)+
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs (x= "Date", y="Q10 Percieved Ability to Manage Workload")+
  geom_text(data = label1, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), inherit.aes = FALSE)+
  geom_text(data = label2, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

I have tried `Q10$Week <- factor(Q10$Week, ordered = TRUE, levels = c("Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8-Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", "Mar 29-Apr 5"))`, but that is weirdly just erasing everything under the column of week.

Any help would be great! THANK YOU!

Please find my data attached below:

```
> dput(Q10)
structure(list(StudentFactor = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 
39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L), .Label = c("789331", 
"796882", "805933", "826523", "827911", "830271", "831487", "832929", 
"834598", "836364", "838607", "839802", "841903", "843618", "852125", 
"855524", "873527", "876406", "879972", "885409", "885650", "888712", 
"894218", "903303", "928026", "932196", "952797", "955389", "956952", 
"957206", "957759", "959200", "962490", "965873", "967416", "968728", 
"969005", "971179", "975424", "976863", "981621"), class = "factor"), 
    Question = c("Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", 
    "Q10", "Q10", "Q10", "Q10"), Type = c("SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
    "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
    "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
    "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
    "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
    "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
    "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
    "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
    "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
    "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
    "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
    "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
    "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
    "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
    "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
    "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
    "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
    "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
    "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS"), 
    College = c("CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CA", "CA", "CA", 
    "CA", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", 
    "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", 
    "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", 
    "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CBS", "CBS", 
    "CBS", "CBS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CBS", 
    "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", 
    "OAC", "OAC", "OAC", "OAC", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CSAHS", 
    "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", 
    "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CPES", "CPES", "CPES", "CPES", 
    "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", 
    "CBS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", 
    "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CPES", "CPES", "CPES", "CPES", "N/A", 
    "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CSAHS", 
    "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", 
    "CBS", "CBS", "CBS", "CBE", "CBE", "CBE", "CBE", "CSAHS", 
    "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", 
    "CBE", "CBE", "CBE", "CBE", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", 
    "CBE", "CBE", "CBE", "CBE", "CPES", "CPES", "CPES", "CPES", 
    "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "CSAHS", "OAC", "OAC", "OAC", 
    "OAC", "CBE", "CBE", "CBE", "CBE", "CBE", "CBE", "CBE", "CBE", 
    "CBE", "CBE", "CBE", "CBE"), Bin = c("Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", 
    "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", 
    "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", 
    "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", 
    "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", 
    "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", 
    "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", 
    "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", 
    "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", 
    "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", 
    "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", 
    "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", 
    "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", 
    "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", 
    "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", 
    "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", 
    "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", 
    "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", 
    "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", 
    "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", 
    "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", 
    "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", 
    "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", 
    "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4", "Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3", "Bin 4"
    ), Week = c("Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5", "Jan25-Feb 1", "Feb 8- Mar 1", "Mar 8- Mar 22", 
    "Mar 29-Apr 5"), Rating = c(0, -1, -1, -0.5, 0, -1, -4, -2, 
    -1, -1.6666667, -2, -2, 0, -0.3333333, -1, -1, 0, -0.3333333, 
    -1, -1, 0, -0.3333333, 0, 0, -1, -0.3333333, 0, -0.5, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -0.3333333, -0.3333333, -0.5, 
    0, -0.3333333, -0.6666667, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 0.6666667, 
    1, 1, 0, -0.3333333, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -0.6666667, -0.3333333, 
    -1, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, -1, -1.3333333, -0.5, 0.5, 0.6666667, 
    1, 1, 0, -0.6666667, -2, -1.5, 1.5, 0.3333333, 0.3333333, 
    0, -1, -1, -1.3333333, -1.5, -1, -0.3333333, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0.6666667, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.3333333, 0, 0, 0, 1.6666667, 2, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.6666667, 
    -2, -0.5, 1, 0.3333333, -1, -1, 1, 0.3333333, 0, 1, 0, -1, 
    -3.6666667, -3, 0, 0, 0.6666667, 1, 0, -0.3333333, -1.3333333, 
    -2.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1.6666667, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, 2, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, -0.3333333, -2, -2)), .Names = c("StudentFactor", 
"Question", "Type", "College", "Bin", "Week", "Rating"), row.names = c(NA, 
-164L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: relevel your Week variable.

Comment: What is `Q10`? Please include a reproducible example.

Comment: Post the results of `str(Q10)`, or better `dput(Q10)`. Almost certainly can be fixed by making your dates an ordered factor like `Q10$Week <- factor(Q10$week, ordered = T, levels = c('Jan25-Feb 1', 'Feb 8-Mar 1', 'Mar 8- Mar 22', 'Mar 29-Apr 5'))`

Comment: `Q10$Week<- factor(Q10$Week, ordered = T)` Do this before plotting.

Comment: @Prradep 
Thank you, I have added my data.

Comment: @Zach, as per your suggestion  tried reordering Week as a factor, but it just ended up removing everything from the Week column completely. I have also added my data

Comment: Based on the data your provided `Q10$Week <- factor(Q10$Week, ordered = T, levels = c('Jan25-Feb 1', 'Feb 8- Mar 1', 'Mar 8- Mar 22', 'Mar 29-Apr 5'))` works fine. Missed a space in the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for you:

```
Q10$Week <- gsub(" ", "", Q10$Week, fixed = TRUE)
Q10$Week <- factor(Q10$Week, ordered = TRUE, levels = c("Jan25-Feb1", "Feb8-Mar1", "Mar8-Mar22", "Mar29-Apr5"))
```

The problem was that the data in column Week was not well formatted! You have too much white spaces and in different positions even for same factor/value. As for example in your data you had a value: `"Feb 8- Mar 1"` but you set in levels that it is `"Feb 8-Mar 1"`, which is incorrect (there is white space after `-` sign in the data)...Eitherway my solution is to remove all the white spaces in the column Week using `gsub` function and further ordering the data.

And using properly fomratted data and your ggplot code:

```
label1 <- data.frame( x = 1,  y = 4, label = "")
label2 <- data.frame( x = 2, y = -4,  label = "")
ggplot(data = Q10, mapping = aes(y = Rating, x = Week, group= StudentFactor, colour=StudentFactor))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  geom_smooth(method = 'loess',  colour= "black", aes(group=1), se= FALSE)+
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs (x= "Date", y="Q10 Percieved Ability to Manage Workload")+
  geom_text(data = label1, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), inherit.aes = FALSE)+
  geom_text(data = label2, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

i got this well formatted plot with ordered x axis:

[image]